# Shapefile to TIGER with OGR

Tags: gdal, ogr

How do I convert a shapefile to TIGER using GDAL (OGR). I try but it throws the following error:

`(layer number)is not a known TIGER/Line layer.`

Answer (score 2):

TIGER is a read only format, see:

http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_tiger.html

Comment: It seems that the docs are wrong.  It supports write, but it must be have very specific parameters or layer names.  Without docs though, I can't help.